# creating a new type of JSONObject through inheritance

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to create a specific type JSONObject that would give me the functionality I need from my program.

So I created a class like this -

```
class JSONSite : JSONObject() {
    val name : String = this.getString("Site")
    
    init { 
        // A lot of leg work  
    }
    
    fun doComplicatedStuff(){}
    fun doDifficultThings(){}
}
```

Then I created an Extension like this -

```
fun JSONObject.getJSONSite(key: String) : JSONSite {
    return this.getJSONObject(key) as JSONSite
}
```

But then when I go to call it -

```
for (key in masterSitesJSON.keys()) {
    val site: JSONSite = masterSitesJSON.getJSONSite(key)
    site.doTheThings()
}
```

But as you probably have guessed, I am getting the following error.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONObject cannot be cast to
> com.sunny.camping.objects.JSONSite

So my question is, is it possible to create a new type of JSONObject (JSONSite in this case) that gives me the new functionality that I need while retaining the base abilities of the JSONObect?

And I would prefer to create a new object/class for my purpose instead of muddying up JSONObject itself with 50 new extensions

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast `JSONObject` to `JSONSite` simply because inheritance is not bidirectional and that means `JSONObject` cannot become `JSONSite` as it may be missing required functionality (naturally `JSONSite` can be casted to its parent as it has all the features of `JSONObject`).